# $P(A \subseteq B)$ Introduction to Probability - Blitzstein

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I am looking at exercise 33.b in Blitzstein's "Introduction to Probability" and are struggling to understand some of the proposed solutions I find.

The exercise asks for $P(A \subseteq B)$ that Alice (A) knows a subset of friends of Bob(B). Each has a 50% chance of being friends with a person.

A proposed solution I have seen just states $\frac{1}{2}^{|A|}$. But if I take the case of $P(A \subseteq B)$ for 1 friend, I would assume it to be $\frac{3}{4}^{A}$, simply by observing the possible outcomes (where the first number in the list is whether A is friends with the person and the second is B):

[0,0]
[0,1]
[1,0]
[1,1]

Of these I would assume $P(A \subseteq B)$ to be true for the outcomes: [0,0], [0,1], [1,1] and thus $P(A \subseteq B)$ = $\frac{3}{4}^{A}$

Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Is $|A|$ meant to be a fixed number or a random number?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are $n$ persons and each of them has probability $0.5$ to be a friend of Alice and also has probability $0.5$ to be a friend of Bob. Moreover there is independence.

Then:$$P(A\subseteq B)=\left(\frac34\right)^n$$
because $\frac34$ is the probability that a specific person is not in $A-B$.

---

Other setup: Alice has $|A|$ friends and each of them has probability $0.5$ to be a friend of Bob.

Then:$$P(A\subseteq B)=\left(\frac12\right)^{|A|}$$
because $\frac12$ is the probability that a specific friend of Alice is not a friend of Bob.

---

I think that more info about the exercise is needed.

Comment: Incidentally, $\sum\limits_{a=0}^n \left(\frac12\right)^{a} \, \mathbb P(|A|=a) = \left(\frac34\right)^{n} $ as you might hope

Comment: @Henry Yes, that is relieving.